# Linear Least Squares Noise vs. Estimator

Tags: statistics, optimization, regression, estimation, least-squares

Is the variance of the estimator the same as the variance of the measurement noise?

What is the difference between the estimator and the noise?

If have an estimator $P'$ and the regression vector $V_N$, Model $t_N$, can I say that $var(t_N) = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ where $\epsilon(k)$ is the noise?

So the estimate of $var(P') = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 (V_N^{T} V_N)^{-1}$?

Or is the estimate of $var(P') = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (residuals)^{2}$.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using the model
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + e_i,$$ 
where $e_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$
Then $\hat\beta_1 = r_{x,Y}S_y/s_x$ and $\hat\beta_0 = \bar Y - \hat\beta_1\bar x,$
are respective estimates of the slope $\beta_1$ and the y-intercept $\beta_0.$
(Also, $r_{x,Y}$ is the Pearson correlation between the $x$'s and the $Y$'s.)

Also $\hat \sigma^2$  is estimated by 
$S_{Y|x}^2 = \frac{\sum_i (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2}{n-2},$
where $\hat Y_i = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_i.$ (The differences
$Y_i - \hat Y_i$ are called residuals.)

The standard deviation $SD(\hat\beta_1) = \sigma_{\hat \beta_1} = S_{Y|x}\sqrt{1/(n-1)S_x^2}$ and
the standard deviation $SD(\hat \beta_0)=\sigma_{\hat \beta_0} = 
S_{Y|x}\sqrt{\frac 1n + \frac{\bar X^2}{(n-1)S_x^2}}.$

In summary, I believe you are referring to the $e_i$ as 'noise'. Then the
 'noise variance' $\sigma^2$ is estimated by
$S_{Y|x}^2.$ And the variances of the estimates of the regression
coefficients *use* this estimate, but are not exactly the same.

An alternate expression for the estimate of $\sigma^2$ is
$$S_{Y|x}^2 = \frac{n-1}{n-2}S_Y^2(1-r_{x,Y}^2).$$

Intuitively if the coefficient of determination $r_{x,Y}^2 = 1,$ then
the data points $(x_i, Y_i)$ are perfectly fit by the regression line. (All residuals are $0.$)
So there is no 'noise variance': $S_{Y|x}^2 = 0.$ By contrast, if
$r_{x,Y}^2 \approx 0,$ then the noise about the line is almost the same
as the variability of the $Y_i,$ and the regression line is of no
use in predicting values $Y$ from values $x.$

Comment: If have an estimator $P'$ and the regression vector $V_N$, Model $t_N$, can I say that $var(t_N) = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ where $\epsilon(k)$ is the noise?

So the estimate of $var(P') = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 (V_N^{T} V_N)^{-1}$?

Or is the estimate of $var(P') = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (residuals)^{2}$.

What is the difference?